# Mysql fetchall method throws "Unread result found" Exception

Tags: python, mysql

I am executing a query against Mysql from a python script. I am using the anaconda distribution of python with the Oracle Mysql module. If I limit the query to ~500 rows it executes successfully. Anything above that results in an "Unread result found" exception. I can't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. The code is as follows:

```
import mysql.connector
import csv

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password',
                          host='server',
                          port='3306',
                          database='db',
                          connect_timeout=2000,
                          buffered=True)

try:

    query = "...large query that returns > 500 records..."

    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)

    print 'this will print'
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print 'this will not print'

    with open("data.csv", "wb") as csv_file:

        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerows(results)

finally:
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

Comment: This is the equivalent in java:

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ;
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://server:3306/db", "user", "password") ;
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
    String query = "...large query that returns > 500 records..." ;
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    convertToCsv(rs); // loop over results and write to csv

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you run out of memory while buffering the rows on memory, your process is certainly killed.Try to use streaming result set instead of that( MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor).

```
cnx = MySQLdb.connector.connect(user='user', password='password',
                          host='server',
                          port='3306',
                          database='db',
                          connect_timeout=2000,
                          buffered=True)

try:

    query = "...large query that returns > 500 records..."
    cursor = MySQLdb.SSCursor(conn)
    #cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
 ..
```

Comment: I just found that this thread also points to the same problem :: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5994545/3378649

Comment: I have 16GB of memory. And I'm not using MySQLdb.

Comment: This results in the same error
rows = cursor.fetchmany(size=500)
    while rows:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(size=500)

Comment: Just use (Count(table)) as a query by identifying one of your tables to see the number of the overall raws ?

Comment: There are 4285 rows returned from the query

Comment: Did you try to increase the time out value ?

Comment: check: cn.query("SET @@session.wait_timeout = 86400") http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: Check this as well, it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py