# Disabling cached results in mysql (using python)

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I am using python 2.7, pyodbc and mysql 5.5. I am on windows

I have query which returns millions of rows and I would like to process it in chunks. 
using the fetchmany function.

He a portion of the code

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=XXXX;User=root; Password='';Option=3;')

cursor_1 = connection.cursor()
strSQLStatement = 'SELECT x1, x2 from X'

cursor_1.execute(strSQLStatement)
# the error occurs here  

x1 = cursor_1.fetchmany(10)
print x1
connection.close()
```

My problem:

1. I get the error **MySQL client ran out of memory**
2. I guess that this is because the `cursor_1.execute` tries to read everything into memory and tried the following (one by one) but to no avail

   1. In user interface (ODBC – admin tools) I ticked the “Don't cache results of forwarding-only cursors”
   2. **connection.query("SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 40000")**

My question:

1. Does pyodbc has the possibility to run the query and serve the results only on demand ?
2. The MySQL manual suggests to [**invoke mysql with the --quick option**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/out-of-memory.html). Can this be done also when not using the command line?

Thanks for your help.

P.S: suggestions for an alternative MySQL module are also welcome, but I use portable python so my choice is limited.

Comment: why don't you just use `LIMIT 10` in the query itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MySQLdb with [SSCursor](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor-class.html) will solve your issues.

Unfortunately the documentation isn't great but it is mentioned in the [user guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#using-and-extending) and you can find an example [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808150/how-to-efficiently-use-mysqldb-sscursor).

Comment: Thanks Mihai. I would very much like to do this using pyodbc or another DB API which works unproblematically on windows (on a portable version I use). This is not the case for MySQLdb windows. But thanks anyway.

Comment: did you try PyMySQL (pure python client) ? it also supports SSCursors, but I have no personal experience with it

Comment: I finally installed ActivePython and MySQLdb but it does not solve the problem. There is still  a memory problem. 
In fact the documentation <http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors-module.html>
says that SSCursor saves results the server (I guess it fetches everything). 

I also tried to set the arraysize cursor_1.arraysize= 2 but it does not help. 
P.S: I did not know that ActivePython is actually portable (there is a zip version without installer). MySQLdb is called there MySQL-python . another related question 337479
I will use sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Use the LIMIT clause on the query string.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

By using

```
SELECT x1, x2 from X LIMIT 0,1000
```

You'll only get the 1st 1k records, then by doing :

```
SELECT x1, x2 from X LIMIT 1000,2000
```

You'd get the next 1k records.

Loop this appropriately to get all your records. (I dont know python so cant help here :( )

Comment: Thanks.  This would be an option of last resort (the nuclear option so to speak).

Comment: Just came by this comment and would like to expand on the comment above.  This is indeed the **nuclear option** b/c you're not telling mysql in which way to order them.  If something was inserted between the two queries you'd get non deterministic results b/c of the way mysql returns rows with no order by.  And order by limit is very inefficient, if it has not been fixed.  a better bet would be `BETWEEN N AND M` and keep track of N and M yourself.