# Use a query in sqlite value - python

Tags: python, sqlite

Does anyone know how to execute a query inside a value in python sqlite

The eroor i am getting is:
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

my code is here:

```
Name = input("Enter the name of the product you want to purchase: >>")
item = Name
qty = input("Enter the Quantity of the product you want to purchase: >>")

today = date.today()
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT CatID from Products where Name=?",(Name,))
result = cursor.fetchall()

 confirm = input("are you sure you want tot buy this product (y/n): >>" )

if confirm == "y":

     ### In this query where it says result i want to execute the data from the result query
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO OrderHistory(Username,Category,Date,Qty,ItemHistory) Values(?,?,?,?,?)",(Username,result,today,qty,Name))

db.commit()

print("Product purchased. Thankyou for your order")

cursor.execute("UPDATE Products SET Qty = (? -1) where Name = ?",(qty,item,))

else:

print("The program will now terminate")
```

Comment: edit question and format code.

Comment: @furas what do you mean

Comment: `result` can be iterator`. You have to get single row from interator and later single element from row.

Comment: your code have empty space at left side so we have to scroll it to see all code. Change it.

Comment: @furas i don't have a clue how to do that can you please help

Comment: if you need only one result from `SELECT` then use `row = fetchone()` and then you should have your ID as `row[0]` so `result = row[0]` or shorter `result = fetchone()[0]`

Comment: @furas i got it to work with by adding result = str(result) but it inserts the value in the data base like this [(7,)] do you know how to make it insert just 7

Comment: fetchall never returns single value but list of rows and every row has columns - even if you expect only single value or single row. You have to get first row from result and later first column from row `result = str(result[0][0])`

Comment: qty = int(input("Enter the Quantity of the product you want to purchase: >>"))
                                cursor = db.cursor()
                                cursor.execute("SELECT Price from Products where Name=?",(Name,))
                                price = cursor.fetchone()
                                map(float(price))
                                newprice = price  * qty

Comment: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: how can i fix it any body? i want to multiply the qty with the price

Comment: see my previous comment  - `fetchone()` always return row (with columns) even if there is only one value - you have to get `price = fetchone()[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also iterate over result:

```
for row in result:
    cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO OrderHistory(Username,Category,Date,Qty,ItemHistory) SELECT CatID,?,?,?,? FROM Products WHERE Name=?",(Username,row,today,qty,Name))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: i got it to work with by adding result = str(result) but it inserts the value in the data base like this [(7,)] do you know how to make it insert just 7

Comment: refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867140/python-mysqldb-get-the-result-of-fetchall-in-a-list

Comment: thanks anyway done by stripping the string works fine