# python mysqldb connect error

Tags: python, mysql-python

My problem occurred as follows:

I use the APIs of mysqldb , the codes like this:

```
 conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='192.168.1.16', user='henry', passwd='password', db='test', charset='utf8')
 cur = conn.cursor()
```

It is ok, the connect mysql is a success, and it works as well with this:

```
select count(*) from songs;   everthing is allright.
```

But if I use sql like this:

```
select * from songs;
```

The error is:

```
connect mysqldb error. the songs table has 5000000 rows.
```

Comment: You are not really showing the Python code you are using for the sql.  Show the code and keep your comments out of the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Bear is correct that you are probably running out of memory. You should use a cursor so that you only load the data you need when you need it.

You can put `cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor` in the connect function, and that should fix the problem.

See [How to efficiently use MySQLDB SScursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808150/how-to-efficiently-use-mysqldb-sscursor).

Answer (score 1):

MySQLdb save all rows and columns of the select statement in the memory, in your case is 5M rows * n columns, so the error may be caused by two reason:  
   1. the result is too large to be saved in memory.  
   2. the result is too large to be transferred via the network connection.  
  
You may try to just return a few rows, not all of them. If you really want to retrieve the entire table, complete it in several times.